# Best way to add values to array (append an item or array_merge())

Tags: php, arrays

Assume we have an array

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
```

We need to get an array

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
```

Should we use

```
$a = array_merge($a, array('d', 'e'));
```

or

```
$a[] = 'd';
$a[] = 'e';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both are identical in this situation since you dont have any ordered or named keys to be concerned about. use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have the values, you have already as an array, then `array_merge()` is ok, but if you loop in something and you get a value at a time then the second option is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you generate the second array. If the second array you wish to append comes from the output of another function, the better choice is `array_merge()`.